# Get selected node from Kivy Recycleview

Tags: python, listview, android-recyclerview, kivy

I've got some programs written in previous versions of Kivy that use ListViews. Using ListViews, it was quite easy to get the selected node via the adapter. However, it is much less clear how to do this with a RecycleView. Now, it is the case that `rv.layout_manager.selected_nodes` can be used to get the selected value, but there are also times where I'm interested in the actual node. Also, the following snippet can be used to generate the nodes, but apparently, they aren't the actual nodes in the RecycleView.

```
opts = rv.layout_manager.view_opts
for i in range(len(rv.data)):
    s = rv.view_adapter.get_view(i, rv.data[i], opts[i]['viewclass'])
    print s.text, s.selected
```

I'd be interested in finding a way of getting the selected node from the RecycleView.

Full code:

```
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior

#Aside: the code in the string would need to be indented back one tab, but it's like this for SO formatting
Builder.load_string('''
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
        rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        key_selection: "True"
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: True
        touch_deselect_last: True
''')


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(random.random())} for x in range(20)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.rv = RV()
        self.rv.layout_manager.bind(selected_nodes=self.selectionChange)
        return self.rv

    def selectionChange(self, inst, val):
        print inst, val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = TestApp()
    b.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please show us your code. in the rv.data you can add a parameter 'selected' = 0 when the node is not selected and 1 when it is this is an example:

```
class TestRecycleView(RecycleView):

   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(TestRecycleView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.data = [{'name': 'test', 'ind':0,'selected': 0}]

class TestBox(RecycleDataBehaviour, BoxLayout):
   def action(self, boss):
      if boss.data[self.ind]['selected'] == 0:
         boss.data[self.ind]['selected'] = 1
      else:
         boss.data[self.ind]['selected'] = 0
```

the kv:

```
<TestRecycleView>:
   viewclass: 'TestBox'
   RecycleBoxLayout:
      default_size: None, 440
      default_size_hint: 1, None
      size_hint_y: None
      height: self.minimum_height
      orientation: 'vertical'
<TestBox>:
   Button:
      on_press: root.action(root.parent.parent)
```

if i understand well you want to print the selectedLabel value:

```
class TestApp(App):
   def build(self):
      self.rv = RV()
      self.rv.layout_manager.bind(selected_nodes=self.selectionChange)
      return self.rv

   def selectionChange(self, inst, val):
      print self.rv.data[val[0]]['text']
```

[proof(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crMQ2.png)

Comment: My mistake. I'd listed the wrong example file. The code is edited in. My goal is to get the selected nodes out of the recycleView.layout_manager.

Comment: I updated my answer, hope is what you wanted @PistolPete

Comment: it turned out that I was looking in the wrong place. My goal was to get the selected widgets, and I was looking in ``rv.layout_manager``. It turns out that I should have been looking in ``rv.view_adapter.views``. But, thanks for the help.